# Android receive value from onActivityResult and set it to a Button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-button, startactivityforresult

With this code, I can easily insert dynamically some layouts. The layout contains a `Button`, which I want to launch `startActivityForResult`. Now when I get the result (text), I want to set it on the `Button`.

```
btnAggiungiCampo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, btnAggiungiCampo);
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_campi, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                View child = null;
                if (item.getTitle().equals(getString(R.string.Text))) {
                    child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inflate_campo, null);
                    rlCampi.addView(child);

                    Button btnGeneraPSW = (Button) child.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
                                btnGeneraPSW.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        Intent inte = new Intent(this, Genera_password.class);
                                        startActivityForResult(inte, REQ_CODE_ACT1);
                                    }
                                });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_ACT1) {

            // how can I set??

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set flag onActivityResult and then add your view in onResume.

Answer (score 8):

Do this in Genera_password Activity after completing all the operations.

```
Intent data=new Intent();
data.putExtra("text",requiredText);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,data);
finish(); //to destroy Genera_password Activity
```

In OnActivityResult of the current activity

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_ACT1) {
            String requredText=data.getExtras().getString("text");
            button.setText(requredText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will fail because the view is created after onActivityResult

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set a text on an ImageButton. ImageButton has no method for this. Instead you have to use a Button, or, if the image is important, use an ImageButton with a TextView beneath.

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:scaleType="centerInside"
      android:id="@+id/yourImageButton"
      android:src="@drawable/yourSource"
    />
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/yourTextView"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

And then set the text you retrieve to your TextView:

```
mYourTextView.setText(retrievedText);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `rlCampi` is a `ViewGroup` and you are adding child in it using `rlCampi.addView(child)`. You can find how many child's are present in your `View` using `rlCampi.getChildCount()`.

Now replace your code with below

```
ImageButton btnGeneraPSW = (ImageButton) child.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
btnGeneraPSW.setTag(rlCampi.getChildCount());
btnGeneraPSW.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Genera_password.class);
        intent.putExtra("btnGeneraPSW_position", (int) v.getTa());
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_ACT1);
    }
});
```

And when you are setting result add these lines

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("btnGeneraPSW_position", getIntent().getIntExtra("btnGeneraPSW_position", -1));
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
```

And inside `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_ACT1) {
            int btnPosition = data.getIntExtra("btnGeneraPSW_position", -1);
            if(btnPosition != -1){
                View childView = rlCampi.getChildAt(btnPosition);
                // now you have your childView and activity result data 
                // using childView find your view and change its text you have from activity result data 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes u should be

Comment: my setting result but not work: Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("btnGeneraPSW_position", tvPassword.getText().toString());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();

Comment: You are not doing well you have to do as i told you to do. You should `intent.putExtra("btnGeneraPSW_position", (int) v.getTag())` instead of `intent.putExtra("btnGeneraPSW_position", tvPassword.getText().toString())`

Comment: with your response I get "null"

Answer (score 1):

You should set result in `Genera_password` activity. You can do this like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.putExtra("btnGeneraPSW_position", tvPassword.getText().toString());
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); 
finish();
```

Then you can get this `String` value from `onActivityResult` like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_ACT1) {
            String tvPassword = data.getExtras().getString("btnGeneraPSW_position");
            ((Button) child.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3)).setText(tvPassword);
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

`onActivityResult` is called before the view is created. It means you cannot set anything to a button because the button doesn't exits yet. As @Qamar said you have to save the result into a variable and the check in `onActivityResume` that variable and set the correct value to the button.

```
Object result = null;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_ACT1) {
            result = data.get....
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
     if (data != null) {
          findViewById(id).setValue(result);
          result = null;
    }

}
```